# Android Virtual Device not accepting Images?

Tags: android-studio, android-virtual-device

I'm not able to upload any images to my Android Virtual Device as i'm using Android Studio 4.1.1?
I'm directly preforming **drag and drop** to emulator it shows uploading but in Download or in any other folder i'm *not getting anything* ?

Comment: maybe you can try device file explorer with drag and drop

Comment: Thank you ! but there is no app like file explorer in any of my emulator.

Comment: do you know about such file explorer inside android studio? view -> tool windows -> file explorer

Comment: i heard for the first time but that directory nothing shows like file explorer

Comment: sure, you will need to find for example sdcard->download and paste file here

Comment: I have posted some instructions for you. check it please

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve a solution via Device File Explorer:

```
View > Tool Windows > Device File Explorer or click the Device File Explorer
```

here:

[image]

where you can find such directory scheme:

[image]

via such method you can **get data** from the mobile device:

[image]

For file **uploading** you can use another way:

[image]

and select a file:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this many help but my emulator still shows 0 images/videos. I restarted emulator too !

Comment: hm... maybe youк device isn't visible inside this explorer?

Comment: I can see it in directory as you suggested but not showing on emulator?

Comment: what you would like to see? As I see on screenshot you see some data inside our device. I'm confused little bit

Comment: My brother i have uploaded images as you given but still i'm not getting those images on my emulator

Comment: you can also press synchronize btn which was shown on picture above, maybe it will help you to see some new files

Comment: can you check another emulator? and also you can check whether you didn't allow to share files for this emulator? I'm working with Genymotion and it works well :)

Comment: Sorry to let you know my laptop will hang if i will install more emulator softwares i have to manage

Comment: you can use also Genymotion, it is much lighter that android studio one

Comment: OK, i'm looking towards that 

Comment: I tried configuring Genymotion with Android Studio but finally ended up with option not visible in Android Studio as i found Genymotion is no longer supported in newer version of Android Studio 

Comment: why it is not supported?)) I'm currently working with it)